# Does negative value of bytes in decimal affect my result in a GF(256)

Tags: java, byte, signed

I have developed a program which can only do the calculations in GF(256) . I have used a byte of array which has random values . Unfortunately since java support only signed data types in my array i have negative  element let say -12 ; - 120 . And over this array i am going to do mathematical operations of GF(256) . So i wanted to know if i use these negative values will these affect the answer i wanted to achieve or it would be the same as all the values of arrays will be positive . I know that signed value of -1 is as unsigned value 255 but i am confused for the result i would receive in java .

Can anyone explain me if the result will be affected or not?

Comment: It depends on what your code does.  How are we supposed to know?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  
My code is going to add and multiply two polynomials . One is from this byte array (with negative values) and another one is set by me with positive ones

Comment: Again, it depends on how your code behaves.  We can't possibly tell you that...